# Segmentation fault in function

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault, callstack

When I run debugging it points to the `line: 105` (and writes "segmentation fault" in the left corner). I don't know what does red line in "Call stack" window mean...

Please, tell waht it is and where can I read more about it.

Here is the function's code:

```
/* Separates stereo file's samples to L and R channels. */
struct LandR sepChannels_8( unsigned char *smp, unsigned long N, unsigned char *L, unsigned char *R, struct LandR LRChannels )
{
    int i;

    if ( N % 2 == 0 )   // Each channel's (L,R) number of samles is 1/2 of all samples.
    {
        L = malloc(N / 2);
        R = malloc(N / 2);
    }
    else
        if ( N % 2 == 1 )
        {
            L = malloc(N + 1 / 2);
            R = malloc(N + 1 / 2);
        }

    int m = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )    // separating
    {
        L[m] = smp[2 * i + 0];   // THIS IS THE "LINE: 105"
        R[m] = smp[2 * i + 1];
        m++;
    }
    return LRChannels; 
}
```

And here is sreenshot of the windows (easier to show it instead of trying to describe)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line in red is your call stack: Basically, it's telling you that the problem occurred inside the the `sepChannels_8()` function, which was called from `main()`. You have, in fact, several bugs in your `sepChannels_8()` function.

Here is my analysis:

```
struct LandR sepChannels_8(unsigned char *smp, unsigned long N, unsigned char *L, unsigned char *R, struct LandR LRChannels)
```

`sepChannels_8` is a function that takes five arguments of varying types and returns a value of type `struct LandR`. However, it's not clear what the five arguments passed to the function are. `unsigned char *smp` appears to be a pointer to your audio samples, with `unsigned long N` being the total number of samples. But `unsigned char *L`, `unsigned char *R`, and `struct LandR LRChannels`, it's not at all clear what the point is. You don't *use* them. `unsigned char *L` and `unsigned char *R`, your function promptly discards any passed-in pointers, replacing them with memory allocated using `malloc()`, which is then thrown away without being `free()`d, and the only thing you do with `struct LandR LRChannels` is simply return it unchanged.

```
{
    int i;

    if ( N % 2 == 0 )   // Each channel's (L,R) number of samles is 1/2 of all samples.
    {
        L = malloc(N / 2);
        R = malloc(N / 2);
    }
    else
        if ( N % 2 == 1 )
        {
            L = malloc(N + 1 / 2);
            R = malloc(N + 1 / 2);
        }
```

Now this is interesting: If the passed-in `unsigned long`, `N`, is an even number, you use `malloc()` to allocate two blocks of storage, each `N / 2` in size, and assign them to `L` and `R`. If `N` is not even, you then double-check to see if it's an odd number, and if it is, you use `malloc()` to allocate two blocks of storage, each `N` in size, and assign them to `L` and `R`. I think you may have intended to allocate two blocks of storage that were each `(N + 1) / 2` in size, but multiplication and division happen before addition and subtraction, so that's not what you get. You also fail to account for what happens if `N` is neither even nor odd. That's OK, because after all, that's an impossible condition... so why are you testing for the possibility?

```
    int m = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )    // separating
    {
        L[m] = smp[2 * i + 0];   // THIS IS THE "LINE: 105"
        R[m] = smp[2 * i + 1];
        m++;
    }
```

Mostly pretty standard: you've got a loop, with a counter, and arrays to traverse. However, your terminating condition is wrong. You're walking down your `smp` data two steps at a time, and you're doing it by multiplying your array index, so your index counter needs to run from `0` to `N / 2`, not from `0` to `N`. (Also, you need to account for that last item, if `N` was odd...). Further, you're using `m` and `i` for the same thing at the same time. One of them is unnecessary, and redundant, and not needed, and extra.

```
    return LRChannels;
}
```

And, return the `LRChannels` struct that was passed in to the function, unmodified. At the same time, you're discarding the `L` and `R` variables, which contain pointers to `malloc()`-allocated storage, now lost.

What were `L` and `R` supposed to be? It almost looks as though they're supposed to be `unsigned char **`, so you could give your allocated storage back to the caller by storing the pointers through them... or perhaps `struct LandR` has two elements that are pointers, and you were intending to save `L` and `R` in the struct before returning it? for `L` and `R`, and `LRChannels`, I don't see why you're passing them to the function at all. You might as well make them all automatic variables inside the function just as `int i` and `int m` are.

Answer (score 0):

You have `malloc`ed `N/2` elements in the array but in the loop, your counter goes from 0 to `N`.  And that will imply that you are trying to access elements from 0 to `N` because you increment `m` on every iteration.  Obviously, you will get a seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of 'smp'?

It either needs to have been allocated prior to the call to sepChannels_8(), or point to a valid placeholder.